# Increasing efficiency - removing tag "discussion" from CV meta

Tags: discussion

have you ever noticed that almost ALL questions here in *meta* are tagged as **"discussion"**? 
When we consider the fact that every question is discussed...it is quite useless tag. So it would be rational to cancel this useless tag, don't you think?

P.S.
I also add tag **"discussion"** to this question...

*...I hope statisticians have a sense of humor:)*

Comment: Did you try posting without using the discussion tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty much a meta-tag for this site.  But since *every* question "must include at least one of [bug feature-request discussion support]," we are at the mercy of the site developers: when the question is *not* about bugs, feature requests, or support, then (by the law of the excluded middle) it *must* be tagged with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).  Unless you wanted to abuse the system, you had no choice when you picked that tag!

Comment: Indeed, one could argue that at some distant point in time, with a full, documented and bug-less feature set, all meta-questions *should* be tagged discussion.